# how i can send a var in a $(var).*** var="#tag" ,html jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, html

i need to send information to my Html. for example

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

var = "'#"+result.tag+"'"  // var = '#tag_dinamy'

// then i need append to my html 

$(var).append("<h1> Good </h1>")

};
 </script>

<p id="tag_dinamy"> </p>
```

I don't need this.

```
$('#tag_dinamy').append("<h1> Good </h1>") //y need pass in a $(var)
```

thanks

Comment: What this has to do with Django?

Comment: you don't need the single quotes where you're setting the `var` literal.

Comment: in Django i have my code, then i send a JsonResponse,  after a read the response in a main.js   in this i have the dinamytag for work.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this: `$('#'+ result.tag)`

Answer (score 0):

That is not how you create a variable with javascript. You should try

```
var sel = "'#"+result.tag;  
$(sel).append("<h1> Good </h1>")
```

Or simply

```
$("#"+result.tag;).append("<h1> Good </h1>")
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work for you.

```
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {

   $('#'+result.tag).append("<h1> Good </h1>")

  };
  </script>

 <p id="tag_dinamy"> </p>
```